# What precautions need to be taken while using sour culture for setting yogurt?

Tags: yogurt

The home made yogurt culture I have is sour.

Is it possible to get non sour yogurt from sour culture?
What precautions need to be taken while using sour culture for setting fresh yogurt?

Answer (score 2):

Hygiene is your most important tool to successful (and safe) yogurt.

Everything should be spotless and sanitized appropriately.

I have made a yogurt that made me really sick, so take that as a warning to maintain good hygiene while working with cultured foods.